# Failure to find org.codehaus.mojo

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have the below pom.xml in one of the projects that I downloaded from a book...

I get the following error,

Failure to find org.codehaus.mojo:mojo-sandbox:pom:3-SNAPSHOT in http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of codehaus snapshot has elapsed or updates are forced

What should be the correct link for --org.codehaus.mojo that I should be using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>wrox</groupId>
  <artifactId>pixweb</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <description></description>
  <pluginRepositories>
<pluginRepository>
<id>codehaus snapshot</id>
<url>http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org</url>
<releases>
<enabled>false</enabled>
</releases>
<snapshots>
<enabled>true</enabled>
</snapshots>
</pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.properties</include>
          <include>**/*.xml</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <directory>src/test/java</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </testResource>
      <testResource>
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <wtpversion>1.0</wtpversion>
          <additionalBuildcommands>
            <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
          </additionalBuildcommands>
          <additionalProjectnatures>
            <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
          </additionalProjectnatures>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>xfire-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
          <executions>
           <execution>
              <goals>
                 <goal>wsgen</goal>
              </goals>
           </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <package>com.wrox.webservice.emailvalidation.client</package>
          <overwrtite>true</overwrtite>
          <generateServerStubs>false</generateServerStubs>
          <forceBare>false</forceBare>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
          <wsdls>
            <wsdl>http://ws.xwebservices.com/XWebEmailValidation/V2/XWebEmailValidation.wsdl</wsdl>
          </wsdls>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
      <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
      <version>${taglibs-standard-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>${jstl-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>${servlet-api-version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>${commons-fileupload-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.1.ga</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
          <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>geronimo-spec</groupId>
      <artifactId>geronimo-spec-jta</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1B-rc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-webflow-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-mock</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
      <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
      <version>${hsqldb-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.directwebremoting</groupId>
      <artifactId>dwr</artifactId>
      <version>${dwr-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>${junit-version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
      <version>${commons-lang-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>${log4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
      <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>rome</groupId>
      <artifactId>rome</artifactId>
      <version>0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.xfire</groupId>
      <artifactId>xfire-aegis</artifactId>
      <version>${xfire-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.xfire</groupId>
      <artifactId>xfire-core</artifactId>
      <version>${xfire-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.xfire</groupId>
      <artifactId>xfire-spring</artifactId>
      <version>${xfire-version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.xfire</groupId>
      <artifactId>xfire-java5</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.xfire</groupId>
      <artifactId>xfire-generator</artifactId>
      <version>${xfire-version}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.xfire</groupId>
      <artifactId>xfire-jaxws</artifactId>
      <version>${xfire-version}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
      <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
      <version>${activemq-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>fm.void.jetm</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetm</artifactId>
      <version>${jetm-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>fm.void.jetm</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetm-optional</artifactId>
      <version>${jetm-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>cglib</groupId>
      <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
      <version>${cglib-version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <properties>
    <activemq-version>4.1.1</activemq-version>
    <spring-webflow-version>1.0.3</spring-webflow-version>
    <spring-version>2.0.5</spring-version>
    <junit-version>3.8.2</junit-version>
    <commons-lang-version>2.1</commons-lang-version>
    <dwr-version>2.0.1</dwr-version>
    <jstl-version>1.0</jstl-version>
    <taglibs-standard-version>1.1.1</taglibs-standard-version>
    <hsqldb-version>1.8.0.7</hsqldb-version>
    <servlet-api-version>2.5</servlet-api-version>
    <log4j-version>1.2.14</log4j-version>
    <commons-fileupload-version>1.1.1</commons-fileupload-version>
    <xfire-version>1.2.4</xfire-version>
    <jetm-version>1.2.1</jetm-version>
    <cglib-version>2.1_3</cglib-version>
  </properties>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

The repository has been moved to https://nexus.codehaus.org/ You probably want to refer to https://nexus.codehaus.org/content/repositories/snapshots/

Comment: The the link does not work any more. But it seems that the repository currently can be accessed from [https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/codehaus-snapshots/](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/codehaus-snapshots/).

Answer (score 0):

Based on Robert Scholte's answer above, this is what worked for me:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>Codehaus Mojo</id>
    <name>Codehaus Mojo</name>
    <url>https://nexus.codehaus.org/content/repositories/releases/</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```